# Finding an element from a list in column of data frame (the type of column is a list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have list and DataFrame as follows, the question is I want to search for each element in the list and if they exist in each list in a column, add a new column and put the word in the new column. Iv tried but my solution is not correct. can anyone please help me?

```
The List : 
list_m = ['KathyConWom',
 'monkeyhead78',
 'acorncarver',
 'bonglez',
 '9NewsQueensland',
 'paulinedaniels',
 'AdvoBarryRoux',
 '_sara_jade_',
 'theage',
 'gaskell_mike',
 'saidtarraf',
 'BroHilderchump',
 'jodyvance',
 'COdendahl',
 'pfizer',
 'RobertKennedyJr',
 'Real_Sheezzii',
 'Kellie_Martin',
 'ThatsOurWaldo',
 'SCN_Nkosi',
 'azsweetheart013']
```

name of DataFrame: test

```
     user_id                  text                                              tweet_id                 user_name                                mention                   
22  1334471712528855040     @KathyConWom @JamesDelingpole Time to stand-up...   1362119551375314948         @KYourrights                        [KathyConWom, JamesDelingpole]  
23  334131548               @KathyConWom @Exp_Sec_Prof It seems like weste...   1362096715877212161         @GowTolson                          [KathyConWom, Exp]  
24  1252182507715526657     @KathyConWom I guess that the hard part would ...   1362096654514552837         @Peterpu52451065                    [KathyConWom]
```

What I want :

```
     user_id                  text                                              tweet_id                 user_name                                mention                                new_col                    
22  1334471712528855040     @KathyConWom @JamesDelingpole Time to stand-up...   1362119551375314948         @KYourrights                        [KathyConWom, JamesDelingpole]          KathyConWom 
23  334131548               @KathyConWom @Exp_Sec_Prof It seems like weste...   1362096715877212161         @GowTolson                          [KathyConWom, Exp]                      KathyConWom
24  1252182507715526657     @KathyConWom I guess that the hard part would ...   1362096654514552837         @Peterpu52451065                    [azsweetheart013]                       azsweetheart013
```

what I tried :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for i in list_m:
    i in test.mention
    test["c"] = i

test
```

Comment: It'll be easier for people to help you if you post code that can be copied/pasted to be run. In your case, this means the list, the code that creates the dataframe, and the code you wrote to perform the search.

Comment: Please put your dataframe.

Comment: ok I would put the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `intersection` operation of `set` to find the common part of two lists.

```py
df['new_col'] = df['mention'].apply(lambda mentions: list(set(mentions).intersection(list_m)))
```

To turn list into string, you can use

```py
df['new_col'] = df['mention'].apply(lambda mentions: ', '.join(set(mentions).intersection(list_m)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def add(x):                                                            
    ret = ''                                                           
    for y in x:                           
        if y in list_m:
            if len(ret) > 0:
                ret += ','
            ret += y
    return ret
    
df['new_col'] = df['mention'].apply(lambda x: add(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`np.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to get the unique **intersection** in list format, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df['new_col'] = df['mention'].map(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, list_m))
```

If you want to convert the list to comma separated string, simply chain it with [`.str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df['new_col'] = df['mention'].map(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x, list_m)).str.join(', ')
```

You can also simply use list comprehension in [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), as follows:

```
df['new_col'] = df['mention'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y in list_m]).str.join(', ')
```